# When using Apollo's optimisticResponse, should the cache update automatically?

Tags: reactjs, apollo

My react application takes advantage of Apollo's automatic cache updates to update the UI. I'd like to use the optimisticResponse option for the `mutate` function but it's not working as expected. I'm wondering if it's necessary to add an `update` option to the mutate function, or if apollo should be able to update the cache automatically using the id's and typenames.

Here are the options I've provided:

```
mutate({                                             
   variables: {id: attendee_record_id, meal_choice: meal_option},                                            
   optimisticResponse: {                                                 
       __typename: 'Mutation',                                              
       updateAttendeeRecord: {                                                   
       __typename: "UpdateAttendeeRecordPayload",                                                    
       attendee_record: {                                                        
           __typename: "AttendeeRecord",                                                         
           id: attendee_record_id,                                                       
           meal_choice: meal_option,                                                     
       }                                                 
   }                                            
})
```

The meal choice gets updated but the result doesn't show up in the UI until the server responds.

Comment: You need to update the cache yourself to get the optimistic ui experience

Comment: how do you update the cache after mutation when using graphql() from react-apollo? @Mikkel

Comment: Have a look at this article https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html There is a heading: "Updating after a mutation"